# I need help from anyone with experience using the ArcSight esm rest API

Tags: python, api, rest, events, arcsight

I was able to get the auth token from the login api but I am trying to use it to query the events api and I am getting a 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url error message. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def action():
    data = {
        'login': 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
    }

    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    try:
        timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print(timestamp)
        r = requests.post(
            'https://host:port/www/core-service/rest/LoginService/login', data=data, verify=False)
        login_request = untangle.parse(r.text)
        user_session_id = login_request.ns3_loginResponse.ns3_return.cdata
        print(user_session_id)

        response = requests.post(
            'https://host:port/detect-api/rest/v1/events/retrieve',
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": user_session_id,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data={
                "ids": 79745681,
                "startTime": timestamp,
                "endTime": timestamp
            },
            verify=False)
        print(response)
        res = untangle.parse(response.text)
        print(res)
```

Can somebody please point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: where is documentation for API? It seems you use it in wrong way.

Comment: if you set `"Content-Type": "application/json"` then it can means you want to send `json` data - so you should use `get(..., json=...)` instead of `get(..., data=...)`

Comment: @furas this api request worked when I curled it on my terminal but it isn't working in my script

Comment: if `curl` works then you should say it in question and you show this `curl` in question (not in comment). There are tools which can convert `curl` to `Python` - ie. https://curl.trillworks.com/ . And when you use `POSTMAN` for tests then it has also functions to generate code for `curl`, `Python` and many other languages.

Comment: @furas I just converted the curl request to python and the output was accurate with what I did on my python script. So I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: these tools sometimes doesn't create correct result. And sometimes only human can convert it correctly. But you still didn't add curl to question - so you only waste time. We can't read in your mind - you have to add ALL information in question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add link to API so I only guess what can make problem.

If you set `"Content-Type": "application/json"` then it can means you want to send `json` data.

So you should use

```
post(..., json=...)
```

instead of

```
post(..., data=...).
```

Using `data=` you send it as `form`, not `json`. And header `Content-Type` can't change it.

And when you use `json=` then you don't have to add `"Content-Type": "application/json"` because `requests` will add it automatically.

---

**EDIT:**

In comment you said that you have working `curl` command (but you didn't said it in question, and you didn't show `curl` in question)

On page https://curl.trillworks.com you can convert `curl` to `Python` (and few other languages) and mostly it works correctly.

**BTW:**

If you use [postman](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) for tests then it has also function to generate code for `curl`, `Python` and many other languages.

You didn't show link to API documentation but often API documentation has examples for `curl` and sometimes even for `Python`.